# Limit of a function and its reciprocal

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ . Suppose I proved $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{f(1-x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)}$$ Let $F(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(1-x)}$. Then, we can see that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{F(x)}$$ Does that mean that $$F(x)=\frac{1}{F(x)}\Rightarrow F(x)=\pm\sqrt{1}$$ being that the value of the limit? Or the indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ makes it impossible to say?

Answer (score 4):

You can't conclude from the limit to the values of $F$.

I suppose the equality of the limits means that both have to exists?

In that case you can just conclude $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)=a$ 
which yields $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1{F(x)}=\frac1a$. Since the limits are equal, we get $a=\frac1a$ and therefore $a\in\{\pm 1\}$. Hence you can conclude
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)=1\text{ or }\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=-1.
$$